# How to UITabBar controller to ViewController in ipad app

Tags: ipad, view, uitabbarcontroller

I have ipad app i want that in viewController to add a tabbar controller and in that tab bar controller Other Views with Navigation controller i have added following some tutorial but it loads my view controller on which i am adding tabbar controller nor the tab bar controller views.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, it can helps you:
https://github.com/alexth/TBSV